# Do the Pokemon you put in Pokemon Dream World affect the Dream World in any way?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Do the Pokemon you put in [Pokemon Dream World](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World), affect the Dream World in any way?

I put [Shuppet](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shuppet_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) in Pokemon Dream World for two days in a row and got a lot of [Spooky Manor](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Spooky_Manor_%28Dream_World_area%29) maps and played a lot of [Blow Out Candles](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World_mini-games#Blow_Out_Candles) on both days.

But today I put [Shuckle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shuckle_%28Pok%C3%A9mon%29) in and I got 90% [Rugged Mountain](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rugged_Mountain_%28Dream_World_area%29), with **at least** 13 [Collect Gems](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_Dream_World_mini-games#Collect_Gems).

Comment: Pokemon-dream-world probably is too narrow to deserve it's own tag. Fifth-gen works just fine to cover it.

Comment: @RavenDreamer the new pokemon is already incoming, and the Pokemon-Dream-World is a feature complete different from pokemon-fifth-gen, with almost not to do with the game it self. (Beside the fact that today only black and white can enter, and the pokemon found in pokemon-dream-world can go to your game). BUT i agree, atm it's only for pokemon-V-gen

Comment: Until then though. :)

Comment: Hmm Why did you @DaveDuplantis remove Pokemon tag, only leaving Pokemon-fifth-gen ??? The pokemon tag is not redundant to pokemon-fifth-gen, is like when you post on stackoverflow `javascript` and `jquery` tags at the same question. PS: Pokemon tag info http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/pokemon/info Your argument looks invalid to me, sorry.

Comment: Gaming.SE hate extra tags for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as awesomesocks42 mentions the type of Pokemon you put to sleep influences which area of the Dream World you will visit.

Here is a list to help you determine which type will increase your chances to visit a particular area:

> Q: Does the type of Pokemon I tuck-in influence which area I go to? A: Yes, depending on
>   the Pokemon's type you'll visit a certain area more often than others,
>   here is a list of which types each area prefers (list is tentative):
>
> **Type** - Area
>
> **Bug** - Pleasant Forest
>
> **Dark** - Spooky Manor
>
> **Dragon** - No Preference
>
> **Electric** - Pleasant Forest
>
> **Fire** - Rugged Mountain
>
> **Fighting** - Rugged Mountain
>
> **Flying** - Windswept Sky
>
> **Ghost** - Spooky Manor
>
> **Grass** - Pleasant Forest
>
> **Ground** - Icy Cave and Rugged Mountain
>
> **Ice** - Icy Cave
>
> **Normal** - Dream Park
>
> **Rock** - Icy Cave and Rugged Mountain
>
> **Poison** - Pleasant Forest
>
> **Psychic** - Spooky Manor
>
> **Steel** - Icy Cave and Rugged Mountain
>
> **Water** - Sparkling Sea

Source: [Smogon Dream World Research Thread](http://www.smogon.com/forums//showthread.php?t=3454925)

Comment: Awesome @Rapida! you nailed it flawless =) Thanks and thanks for the late but still great answer!

Answer (score 2):

yes, they do, as of the global link redesign. I am yet to discover exactly which areas are accessed more by which pokemon, but there is now a correlation, for instance, tucking in a flying type will nearly always result in going to the windswept sky, and tucking in an ice type will nearly always result in going to the icy cave.